# USB showing 2 devices when 1 connected

Tags: usb, partitioning

I have a usb which when plugged in it display like 2 devices (like if you connected your phone and showed you phone and sdcard storage). Is there a way to fix that and make as a single USB again?

[image: 1.1GB Usb details] 
[image: 872MB USB details]

As you can see from the image above there is one with 872MB and the other with 1.1GB shown in disks (but there is only 1 USB connected). Also when I open gParted it shows as 2 devices and not 1 with 2 partitions.

Comment: Most likely that device has _two_ "disks", so two partitions. From that point of view the display is _correct_.

Comment: @arkascha I know that but is it possible to turn it back to a single partition drive ?

Comment: Sure that is possible. You just have to create a new partition table on the device. USB sticks typically act exactly like "hard drives". Partitions are something you can define yourself. Have a try: `sudo fdisk /dev/sdc`, and read the man page of fdisk: `man fdisk`. Note however that this will erase all files on that device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have two partitions on your drive.

The simplest way to fix that is to delete the partitions and create a new large partition that uses all the space, but this will delete any data you have on the stick so make sure to back it up first.  The bold text is what you should write, the regular text is output in the terminal:

```
$ **sudo fdisk /dev/sdc**
Command (m for help): **d**
Partition number (1-2): **1**
Command (m for help): **d**
Command (m for help): **n**
Command action
  e  extended
  p  primary partition (1-4)
**p**
Partition number (1-4): **1**
First cylinder (1-x, default: 1): **<RETURN>**
Using default value 1
Last cylinder of +size or +sizeM or +sizeK (1-x, default x): **<RETURN>**
Command (m for help): **w**
```

Now you should have a clean partition using the entire USB drive.  Time to create a file system:

```
$ **sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdc1**
```

This should create a FAT32 file system compatible with most computers and other stuff you can insert a USB stick into.

Comment: This is my first answer, so I'm not entirely sure on the markup yet.  Seems like bold doesn't work in code blocks, which I guess is logical, I hope the meaning in my text is clear anyway.

Comment: Tried your commands and everything completes without an error but nothing changes when I unplug and plug back in the USB. I think the error might be in the firmware itself (might be wrong about this)

Comment: Maybe.  What kind of device is it?  Some USB thumb drives have some weird handling with encryption and stuff that makes it impossible to alter them too much.

Did fdisk say anything when you ran the 'w' command?

Comment: For the usb device type not sure, since it is device I got from a hostess and has no manufacture's info on it. When I ran the w command I got this:
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.

Comment: You can try deleting the partitions, not creating a new partition (just ignore the 'n' command in fdisk and go directly to 'w') and then running "sudo mkfs.vfat -I /dev/sdc" and see if that helps at all.

That should place a file system directly on the drive, without a partition table.  Some thumb drives are configured like that.

Other than that I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.  Best of luck with your drive.